# Grapchis 2D draw image changing color of Image

Tags: java, bufferedimage, graphics2d

I am trying to attach different images into a image. This is happening but after attaching the color of the image changes. Here is my existing code

```
BufferedImage baseImg = getBaseImage(src);
Graphics2D g = baseImg.createGraphics();
BufferedImage bmg = getBufferedImageFromSrc(path);

String[] coords = coord.split(",");
g.drawImage((Image)bmg,(int) Double.parseDouble(coords[0]),(int) Double.parseDouble(coords[1]), 60,60,Color.white,null);
g.dispose();

 String path = "C://resources/temp.jpeg";  
 ImageIO.write(bimg, "jpeg", new File(path));
```

i am able to add the image to the base image at the specified co-ordinates but the base image colour is getting changed. 
Here is a sample image[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like the typical JPEG with transparency problem... Does changing the format to PNG help? If that works, but you need/prefer JPEG format, you can probably just convert the output image to `BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR` or `TYPE_INT_RGB` (ie. no transparency) before writing, and it should be okay.

Comment: @haraldK it worked when I converted to PNG. Thanks